# CSS - flexbox height 100% don't consider children's heights

Tags: html, css

```css
div.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100%;
}

div.container div.block {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

div.container div.advanced-items {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  height: 100%;
}

div.container div.advanced-items span {
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="block">
    <span>some data here</span>
  </div>
  <div class="block">
    <span>some data here</span>
  </div>
  <div class="advanced-items">
    <span>1. item</span>
    <span>2. item</span>
    <span>3. item</span>
    <!-- more items here -->
  </div>
</div>
```

`div.advanced-items` height value is setted to `100%`, but it somehow equals to whole `div.container` height. But I need to fill the remaining height of the `div.container`, considering childrens height.

Please, help me, how to make it?

Answer (score 0):

*I need to fill the remaining height of the `div.container`, considering children height.*
exactly it's what happened to see how it happened just add `border` to the `div.advanced-items` to see how much space it wrapped

```css
div.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100%;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

div.container div.block {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

div.container div.advanced-items {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  height: 100%;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

div.container div.advanced-items span {
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="block">
    <span>some data here</span>
  </div>
  <div class="block">
    <span>some data here</span>
  </div>
  <div class="advanced-items">
    <span>1. item</span>
    <span>2. item</span>
    <span>3. item</span>
    <!-- more items here -->
  </div>
</div>
```

now you the `div.advanced-items` is wrapping all left height except the one wrapped by the above `divs` but you can make them share the height of its parent equally by set their `height` to `100%`

```css
div.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100%;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

div.container div.block {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100%;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

div.container div.advanced-items {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  height: 100%;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

div.container div.advanced-items span {
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="block">
    <span>some data here</span>
  </div>
  <div class="block">
    <span>some data here</span>
  </div>
  <div class="advanced-items">
    <span>1. item</span>
    <span>2. item</span>
    <span>3. item</span>
    <!-- more items here -->
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you want like this? :

```css
div.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100%;
}

div.container div.block {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

div.container div.advanced-items {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  height: 100%;
}

div.container div.advanced-items span {
  height: calc(100% / var(--item-count));
  min-height : 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="block">
    <span>some data here</span>
  </div>
  <div class="block">
    <span>some data here</span>
  </div>
  <div style="--item-count:3;" class="advanced-items">
    <span>1. item</span>
    <span>2. item</span>
    <span>3. item</span>
    <!-- more items here -->
  </div>
</div>
```

Or maybe this? :

```css
div.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100%;
}

div.container div.block {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

div.container div.advanced-items {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: stretch;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  height: 100%;
}

div.container div.advanced-items span {
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="block">
    <span>some data here</span>
  </div>
  <div class="block">
    <span>some data here</span>
  </div>
  <div style = "--itemCount:3;" class="advanced-items">
    <span>1. item</span>
    <span>2. item</span>
    <span >3. item</span>
    <!-- more items here -->
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Why not answered this ? your problem is solved ? or what do you want ?